# How could I allow only unique strings in a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcomponent

I have a JList that holds a bunch of strings . I would like it to act like a Set , so that it will only hold unique values . Is there any way to achieve this without checking that a new string doesn't already exist there ?

Comment: To what purpose?  Is it necessary to iterate in the order items were added?  Is it necessary to randomly access the items? Why does a set not work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at the docs: [1.4.2](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) | [Java 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)

You can set your own ListModel via JList#setModel(ListModel) which might be backed by e.g. a HashSet instead of the Vector which is used by default.

See also [ListModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) and [AbstractListModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html)

Comment: LinkedHashSet would make more sense, but it'd still be an awkward O(n^2) operation to, say, repaint the widget.